# How to create auto delete queue using Camel RabbitMQ component

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

I would like to consume from an auto deleting anonymous queue with a routing key of "", bound to a durable exchange using Camel's RabbitMQ component. When I set the endpoint like this (reformatted for readability):

```
rabbitmq://localhost:6672/br.processor?
    autoAck=true&
    autoDelete=false&
    bridgeEndpoint=true&
    concurrentConsumers=1&
    durable=true&
    exchangeType=topic&
    prefetchCount=2000&
    prefetchEnabled=true&
    queue=&
    routingKey=&
    username=xxxx&
    password=xxxxxx&
    vhost=xxxx
```

I receive an anonymously named durable queue, bound to the correct exchange, with a routing key set to the queue's name.

I looked at the code (2.14.2), and it appears the queue will always have the same durability as it's exchange, but the routing key will only be set to the blank string when the routing key is left unspecified (`null`). When I tried that, the routing key was still set to the queue's name. When I specify a routing key, I do get the expected routing key.

Looking around here and elsewhere, I found [Avoid automatic binding with RabbitMQ and Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27643910/7355), but not declaring the exchange and queue are causing issues.

Is it possible to bind a queue using the blank routing key using Camel?

Answer (score 0):

Using a fanout exchange there is no need for a routing key

```
to("rabbitmq://"+System.getenv("rabbitmq_host") + ":" +
                System.getenv("rabbitmq_port") + "/myXchange_fanout?"
                        + "connectionFactory=#customConnectionFactory&"
                        + "exchangeType=fanout&"
                        + "queue=test_fanout&"
                        + "autoDelete=false&"
                        + "vhost=" + System.getenv("rabbitmq_vhost"))
```